# sinatra file_config gem not working in staging

Tags: sinatra, yaml, configuration-files

I am using [this](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/config_file.html) gem 
and it's working for production env and development , but not staging:

here is the main.rb

```
set :environments, %w{development test production staging}
config_file 'config/config.yml'
```

and the config/config.yml

```
development: &development
  sub1:
    pay_to_email: test1@gmail.com

test:
  <<: *development

staging:
  <<: *development  

production:
  <<: *development
```

Answer (score 5):

figured out why I have to set it after the register Sinatra::ConfigFile
like so :

```
 register Sinatra::ConfigFile   
 set :environments, %w{development test production staging}
 config_file 'config/config.yml'
```

Comment: Glad you found and answer, and kudos for coming back to answer your own question, especially when it's one of your first. +1.